# In Google Test Framework, how to expect a function call OR another function call?

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

How is it possible to put in logical OR two `EXPECT_CALL` macros? Due to external factor, my test could result in a call to `on_found()` or to a function called `on_not_found()`. For my test scope is the same, because the important thing is that the search has been made. But I do not have access to the internal `search()` function and expect a call to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add some boolean variables to the test and make them true when `on_found()` or `on_not_found()` is called, and check logical OR of the variables at the end of the test. For example,

```
auto onFoundCalled = false;
auto onNotFoundCalled = false;
EXPECT_CALL(mockObj, on_found())
    .Times(AtMost(1)).WillRepeatedly(InvokeWithoutArgs([&onFoundCalled]
{
    onFoundCalled = true;
}));
EXPECT_CALL(mockObj, on_not_found())
    .Times(AtMost(1)).WillRepeatedly(InvokeWithoutArgs([&onNotFoundCalled]
{
    onNotFoundCalled = true;
}));

RunSomeCode();

ASSERT_TRUE(onFoundCalled || onNotFoundCalled);
```